# Row within a row with JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysqli

I have a webpage where it shows the lists of Projects and the monitoring of its progress/finances for every quarter. As shown below:

[image: Figure One]

As you can see, my table is comprises of Project Name and a lists of sub-title's underneath it. And a series of columns per each quarter. Thru `PHP` I was able to populate the list of sub-titles under the Project Name, which also being fetched from the server side. Here's the code:

```
          $sql = mysqli_query($con," My SELECT Statement ");
          $i=0;
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
            $ptitle  = $row['Title'];
            $iname   = $row['Item'];

          if($i%1)
            {
            ?>
            <?php } else { ?>
            <tr>
            <?php } ?>
            <td width="25%"><?php echo $ptitle; ?></td>
            <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><?php echo "<ul style='list-style-type: none;'><li>".nl2br($iname)."</li></ul>"; ?></td>
            <td contenteditable="true" name="v1"></td>
```

**Note:** ptitle = ProjectName and iname = Semi-title underneath the Project's name.

Now, as you can see, the Project Name column literally *"conquer"* a single row on the left. Yet, the rows under the column of each quarter, should have its own separately, and must be parallel to the every sub-title underneath the Project Name. (Please refer to the image above for this) the only problem am encountering is... *how can I make an editable row from inside a row, without affecting mysqli result?* coz basically my table right now is kinda look like this:

[image: Figure Two]

Anyone who's more experience on this? I need your help.

**PS:** ...and oh! You might be wondering why do I include `JSON` in the title? It is because, I originally use `JSON` for editing those table rows before I even use `mysqli_fetch_array`. But when I include the results of the `array` inside the `<table>` tag, everything's changed and `JSON` is no longer working. So as of now, I am force to do it manually, meaning typing each `<td contenteditable=true>` in all of those rows. Yet, its not the desired output since I need another row within an existing row. Ideas? Anyone?

Figure Two:

[image: Figure Two]

Figure Three:

[image: Figure Three]

Comment: "8th Qtr"? There can only be 4 quarters in a year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Count the number of lines in `$iname`, and then use a loop to create that many rows of contenteditable cells. You can also use this in the `rowspan` attribute of the `<td>` containing the title and subtitles.

```
$rows = substr_count($iname, "\n") + 1;
for ($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++) {
    echo "<tr>";
    if ($i == 0) { ?>
        <td rowspan='<?php echo $rows;?>' width='25%'><?php echo $ptitle . "<br>" . nl2br($iname);?></td>
    <?php }
    ?>
    <td contenteditable="true" name="v1"></td><td contenteditable="true" name="v2"></td>...
    </tr>
<?php }
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/gp9z8P)

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work on me. The loop goes on and on for project name's subtitle, but it doesn't add another row. Plus, I don't think that's the `foreach` proper command. Isn't it `for-loop` you actually meant?

Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo.

Comment: I don't understand why it's not adding multiple rows. Am I correctly understanding that `$iname` is a single string with all the subtitles separated by newline?

Comment: I can't say its a single string coz am using a `varchar` type there. But yes, `$iname` is meant for the sub-titles under each project name.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. Are all the different subtitles in one row of the MySQL table, or do they come from multiple rows? Could you add sample table contents to the question?

Comment: I assumed since you used `nl2br($iname)` that they're all in one row of the table, and you need to add the `<br>` tags to spread them over multiple lines in the table cell on the web page.

Comment: No, not all. Only the sub-titles are inside one row. That's why I used `nl2br` for each sub-titles. And for each sub-titles are like sub-editable rows.

Comment: So the subtitles are like `Number of items\nNUmber of equipments delivered\nNUmber of items distributed`? Then I think my code should work.

Comment: Ugh! I had two serious typos. `if ($i = 0)` should use `==`, and I was missing a `?` after `echo $rows;`

Comment: Sorry, but still it doesn't work. It only shows endless loop for the sub-titles. and that's all.

Comment: How can it be an endless loop? It's a simple `for` loop that repeats `$rows` times. What's the value of `$rows`? Have you tried to do any debugging of it?

Comment: Actually Sir, I was the first one to debug it, the moment I saw the `foreach` misuse. And also changed the `=` to `==` That's why, the moment you suggest it, I knew it won't gonna work.

Please refer to the Figure Two above, to see what the actual output looks like.

Comment: Please post sample database contents. I suspect my problem is that I'm misunderstanding the data.

Comment: The sample output looks like it might be due to unbalanced opening and closing tags.

Comment: I've also checked the opening and closing tags. My initial suspicion was on the `while-loop` so I tried to place the `}` of `for-loop` before the `while-loop` but what it did was it showed only three rows dividing a cell for 1st quarter.

As per the database contents, I have already posted it on the codes above.

Comment: Where did you post the DB contents? Is that the blurred image? I thought that was the resulting web page. Can you post something as plain text so I can copy and paste it?

Comment: I just tried running my code inside another loop to simulate reading multiple rows from the DB, I didn't get anything staggered like the image you show.

Comment: Sir, the blurred image are the actual DB contents of `$iname`
I tried to create a separate `php` page, because I thought the endless loop might have something to do with `JSON`. But what I got is only 3 rows out of 5 sub-titles.

I'm starting to think that this feat am trying (you know trying to add content-editable rows beside a single-columned `mysqli_result`) is impossible. 

So I might gonna to separate them instead, in that way I could guarantee that there's enough row for each one of them. Sad thing.

Comment: Why would this be impossible? There's nothing special about contenteditable rows. I think you just haven't specified the relationship between the database contents and how it should be displayed clearly enough.

Comment: I still can't figure out what you're trying to show in that blurred image. It doesn't look like a PHP string. Is it one row from the database or multiple rows? Where are all the borders coming from? It looks more like a web page than a database value.

Comment: Are you storing HTML in the database?

Comment: I think its impossible because am pulling those blurred image (the sub-titles or `$iname` under one database table column which is `Item`) then populate it inside an `html/JSON: <table>` where the next column should be content-editable for each sub-titles under `Item`. <br>

Those blurred image you see are stored inside a DB table_column named `Item`

Comment: Very few things are impossible. Some things are just harder to code. But it starts with understanding what you're trying to do. I wish you would show the database contents instead of images. Can you make a sqlfiddle?

Comment: Sir, all the DB contents are set on varchar/text. I don't think its necessary to display the actual subtitles. Besides, the contents in the sample image atop is somehow similar to it. <br />
`Number of items` <br />
`Number of Equipment Delivered` etc...

Comment: If the DB contents contain `<br/>`, why are you calling `nl2br()` in your script? I thought it contains newlines, which is why I used `substr_count($iname, "\n")` to count the number of lines.

Comment: I used `nl2br` because the elements (or the sub-titles as I call them) under the Project name are under one column/row in the database. As in one `INSERT` that is why am having a hard time doing to row within a row.

Comment: But your data seems to already contains `<br>` for the line breaks, you don't need to add it.

Comment: Please refer to Figure Three. That's how I saved my data

Comment: I'm sorry, but I give up. As far as I can tell, my code should work. It works with the sample data I put in my demo. Your data is obviously different, but I can't tell what's different about it. Look at my demo and figure it out. You're a programmer, debug the  thing.

Comment: I'm still debugging it even upto this point, Sir. There's no problem in your sample code, it will surely work because you defined the values inside the `$iname` however, like you've said, mine is quite different. Because am pulling a data under one row and column. Thanks for the help anyways.

Should I couldn't find any solution, I'll pick your's as the answer so I could close this question.